# Creating a new column in dataframe based on multiple conditions from other rows and columns? Including rows that are null? - Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, conditional-statements

I am working on a dataframe in pandas I imported from a spreadsheet, and am attempting to make a new column based on multiple conditional requirements from other columns/rows.

The code I have used so far to create a new column called 'SPOTTED' is below:

```
df['SPOTTED'] = np.where((df['Work_Date'].notnull()) & (df['Time_Code'] == 'WRK'), 'No', ' ')
```

Which produces the output in the image below, creating the 'SPOTTED' column, and only filling rows in the column with 'No' where values in the 'Time_Code' column are 'WRK' and rows in the 'Work_Date' column are not blank/null:

Current Output of Code on sheet:

[image: Current Output of Code on sheet]

I would like to do exactly this, but include multiple categories under the 'Time_Code' column, besides just 'WRK'.

When I attempt something like this to target multiple 'Time_Code' values the same way and update the 'SPOTTED' column:

```
df['SPOTTED'] = np.where((df['Work_Date'].notnull()) & (df['Time_Code'] == 'WRK'), 'No', ' ')

df['SPOTTED'] = np.where((df['Work_Date'].notnull()) & (df['Time_Code'] == 'OFF'), 'No', ' ')

df['SPOTTED'] = np.where((df['Work_Date'].notnull()) & (df['Time_Code'] == 'VAT'), 'No', ' ')
```

Python only executes one of the lines of code and applies to the dataframe, instead applying all three to create and update the 'SPOTTED' column.

I am trying ultimately to export the data frame to a CSV file once I'm finished and able to get this down.

I would appreciate any help/insight, still learning my way around python and pandas for work.

Thank you! And apologies for any poor explanations.

Comment: Please include any data or code as text in your post itself, not as an image. You also haven't shared any input data. See: [mcve]. What are the possible values for Spotted? If it's just Yes/No/None, use a boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the code you shared for assigning multiple values doesn't work is because `df['SPOTTED'] =` assigns to the **entire** column. Therefore the code keeps creating and overwriting the same column.

Next time you encounter an issue of the sorts, try looking at the contents of `df` after each operation.

---

I believe this is the most idiomatic solution. I stole the dummy data from @Henry Yik, I hope they don't mind.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'work_date': [1, 2, 3, 4, np.nan], 'time_code': ['WRK', 'OFF', 'VAT', 'BONUS', 'OT15']})

select_time_codes = ['VAT', 'WRK', 'OFF']

df.loc[df['work_date'].notna() & df['time_code'].isin(select_time_codes), 'spotted'] = 'No'
```

This is what the DataFrame looks like afterwards:

```
   work_date time_code spotted
0        1.0       WRK      No
1        2.0       OFF      No
2        3.0       VAT      No
3        4.0     BONUS     NaN
4        NaN      OT15     NaN
```

The values are assigned the string `'No'`, and the `NaN` are left untouched, pending clarification from you on the possible values and their uses.

Comment: This is perfect, and solves my issues, thank you so much, it is appreciated.  Especially the explanation for the overwriting of the column from I'm prior code.

Comment: @SlimJim You’re welcome! Is it all clear now, no further questions?

Comment: yes, I am able to logically understand the process, creating the list of time codes to filter through using isin, and combining it successfully with the notna() for work_date values.  It is really appreciated, thanks again.

Comment: @SlimJim I'm glad my answer was helpful :)

Comment: @SlimJim Oh i forgot to ask if you saw my question on the main post!

Comment: Hey @Alexander Cecile, I saw your comment on using  minimal reproducible examples but forgot to respond to it, I will definitely do so going forward, makes more sense to do that then posting a image, still adapting to using Stackoverflow properly. I'm sure I will have other python/programming questions in the near future, so good suggestion. Thanks again!

Comment: @SlimJim Yes, that, although I was thinking of the part about the use of “Yes”/“No” etc.

Comment: ahh my mistake, the possible values were 'yes', 'no', and 'maybe', for the spotted row.